# Scheduled Grid Updates

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, sales-order

> Recently I studied the Magento user guide. I have seen **Scheduled
>   Grid Updates** from the following link.
>
> http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/order-grid-updates-schedule.html
>
> But I didn't understand what it is and how it will be useful? Can
>   anyone explain this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronous Indexing

That take care about

- Customer Grid
- Orders Grid
- Invoices Grid
- Shipments Grid
- Credit Memos Grid

Magento has a cronjob that take care change log of these main tables (sales_order,...), After you are inserts new Order into sales_order and absolutely you much install Magento default cron jobs ([See Configure and run cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html), Magento will copy and insert that record into sales_order_grid while Asynchronous Indexing cron is running, This option save place order time, customer Register Time

I'm working for improve my English.